# StackOverflow Public Dataset is Old?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is the public dataset on BigQuery for StackOverflow no longer being maintained?  I'm trying to search for tags used in 2020-2021, but when I write a very simple query, I get no results?

For example,

```
tags, creation_date FROM `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.stackoverflow_posts` where  creation_date > timestamp("2018-1-1") LIMIT 1000
```

Returns no rows.

It looks like there are no posts in the dataset from 2018 onwards?  Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the `Dataset info` section of the dataset,
it had last modified in 2019. I don't think this public dataset is consistently being updated.

`Last modified: Mar 21, 2019, 6:24:19 AM`

[image]

p.s.
The table that you are looking at was last modified in 2017. The detailed information of the `dataset` and `table` can be found by clicking the element in BigQuery console.

[image]